# How to send input to a batch file being run by Python?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, python-3.x, popen

I've got a python file that attempts to execute a batch file:

```
from subprocess import Popen

batch_input = [List with lots of strings in it]

BATCH_FILE_NAME = r"mybat.bat"
BATCH_FILE_LOCATION = r"C:\dir\that\has\file"

p = Popen(BATCH_FILE_NAME, 
          cwd=BATCH_FILE_LOCATION, 
          shell=True)

stdout,stderr = p.communicate()

p.terminate()
```

Now what I want to do is for every entry in the list `batch_input`, send that input to the batch script. In pseudo code it would be something like:

```
for i in batch_input:
    p.send_input(i)
```

I'd also like to be able to print the output.

EDIT:

Made some progress

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(BATCH_FILE_NAME,
          cwd=BATCH_FILE_LOCATION,
          shell=True,
          stdin=PIPE,
          stdout=PIPE,
          stderr=PIPE)

for entry in batch_input:
    stdout,stderr = p.communicate(entry.encode('utf-8'))
```

This will send the first line in the list, but will send empty strings for the rest of the attempted inputs until it eventually fails with:

```
ValueError: cannot send input after starting communication
```

With my line

```
    stdout,stderr = p.communicate(entry.encode('utf-8'))
```

being the top of the stack trace

Comment: Why don't you concatenate all the inputs together, and send that in one communicate()?

Comment: I tried that with `'\n'.join(batch_input)` and then sending that into communicate, but it doesn't work - it looks like it tries to send everything all on one line

Comment: Actually scratch that - doing it with '\r\n'.join.. again sends the first string, then a bunch of empty strings.